# Add text to image VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, swiper.js

I have a swiper that shows me pictures that I specify with an array. But I need to add text to these pictures (I need the text to be in the picture), but I cannot solve this problem. Maybe someone knows how to do this?

HTML

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-swiper:mySwiper="swiperOption" @someSwiperEvent="callback">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide "   v-for="banner in banners" :key="banner">
              <img :src="getImage(banner)">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
 export default {
    data() {
      return {
         banners: [
           'Block1.png' , 'Block2.png' , 'Block3.png' ,'Block4.png'
         ] ,

         words :[
           'ABOUT AS' , 'WE OFFER' , 'OUR STAFF' , 'PORTFOLIO'
         ],

        swiperOption: {
          slidesPerView: 'auto',
          centeredSlides: true,
          spaceBetween: -400,
          pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
            clickable: true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    methods : {
      getImage(src){
        return require(`~/assets/image/banners/${src}` )
      },
      callback (){

      },
      addWords(){

      },
    },
  }
```

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Actually adding the word in the html or getting the matching word for the picture? You can try: v-for="(banner, index) in banners", and then use index to get the corresponding word in the words array. You can also restructure your "banners" variable into an array of objects, like so: [{ banner: 'A', word: 'a word"}, { banner: 'B', word: 'b word']]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `banners` attribute to be an `array` of `objects` instead of a simple array.

Each object inside the array should have it's `url` and `label`:

```
...
    banners: [
        {img: "block1.png", label: 'my label'},
        {img: "block2.png", label: 'label 2'},
    ],
```

Then, on your loop, you can easily access the label for each banner:

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div v-for="banner in banners" :key="banner" class="swiper-slide">
    <p>{{ banner.label }}</p>
    <img :src="getImage(banner.img)">
</div>
```

Or you can do what Cathy Ha mentioned in the comment above: use the index on the loop and call `{{ words[index] }}`